# Merging Arrays of Objects by Key/Values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two separate arrays of objects that I need to merge based if a specific key value matches. Might make more sense after analyzing the data:

**Array 1**

```
let categories = [
    { id: 5, slug: 'category-5', items: []  },
    { id: 4, slug: 'category-4', items: []  },
    { id: 3, slug: 'category-3', items: []  },
]
```

**Array 2**

```
let items = [
    { id: 5, data: [{ title: 'item title', description: 'item description' }] },
    { id: 5, data: [{ title: 'item title 2', description: 'item description 2' }] },
    { id: 4, data: [{ title: 'item title 4', description: 'item description 4' }] },
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
let mergedOutput = [
    { id: 5, slug: 'category-5', 
        items: [
            { title: 'item title', description: 'item description' },
            { title: 'item title 2', description: 'item description 2' }
        ]
    },
    { id: 4, slug: 'category-4',
        items: [
            { title: 'item title 4', description: 'item description 4' },
        ]
    },
    { id: 3, slug: 'category-3', items: []  },
]
```

So....I need to add **Array 2** to **Array 1** if their id's match.
**Array 1** will stay the same, but if **Array 2** matches, the *items* property of **Array 1** (empty) will be replaced by the data property of *Array 2*

I know this is a pretty basic / and redundant question, but I can't find the resources for my use case / object structure.

I was able to easily group arrays with lodash -- so if there is a similar solution with that library -- that would good! Or just some direction would suffice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop first array and then use `filter` to get objects with same id as current element and add that items to current object.

```js
let categories = [
    { id: 5, slug: 'category-5', items: []  },
    { id: 4, slug: 'category-4', items: []  },
    { id: 3, slug: 'category-3', items: []  },
]

let items = [
    { id: 5, data: [{ title: 'item title', description: 'item description' }] },
    { id: 5, data: [{ title: 'item title 2', description: 'item description 2' }] },
    { id: 4, data: [{ title: 'item title 4', description: 'item description 4' }] },
]

categories.forEach(function(e) {
  var i = items.filter(a => a.id == e.id).map(a => a.data);
  e.items = i;
})

console.log(categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the items into categories:

```
let res = items.reduce((a, b) => {
  let it = a.find(e => e.id === b.id);
  if (! it) return a;
  it.items = it.items.concat(b.data);
  return a;
}, categories);
```

```js
let categories = [{
    id: 5,
    slug: 'category-5',
    items: []
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    slug: 'category-4',
    items: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    slug: 'category-3',
    items: []
  },
];

let items = [{
    id: 5,
    data: [{
      title: 'item title',
      description: 'item description'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    data: [{
      title: 'item title 2',
      description: 'item description 2'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    data: [{
      title: 'item title 4',
      description: 'item description 4'
    }]
  },
];

let res = items.reduce((a, b) => {
  let it = a.find(e => e.id === b.id);
  if (! it) return a;
  it.items = it.items.concat(b.data);
  return a;
}, categories);

console.log(res);
```

It might be faster to get the ids in an object first, so we don't have to use `find` on the same id many times:

```
function merge(result, toMerge, mergeInto) {
    let i = 0, hm = {};
    for (let {id} of categories) {
        hm[id] = i;
        i++;
    }
    return toMerge.reduce((a,b) => {
        let it = a[hm[b.id]];
        if (!it) return a;
        it[mergeInto] = it[mergeInto].concat(b.data);
        return a;
    }, result);
}
```

```js
let categories = [
    { id: 5, slug: 'category-5', items: []  },
    { id: 4, slug: 'category-4', items: []  },
    { id: 3, slug: 'category-3', items: []  },
];

let items = [
    { id: 5, data: [{ title: 'item title', description: 'item description' }] },
    { id: 5, data: [{ title: 'item title 2', description: 'item description 2' }] },
    { id: 4, data: [{ title: 'item title 4', description: 'item description 4' }] },
];

function merge(result, toMerge, mergeInto) {
    let i = 0, hm = {};
    for (let {id} of categories) {
        hm[id] = i;
        i++;
    }
    return toMerge.reduce((a,b) => {
        let it = result[hm[b.id]];
        if (!it) return a;
        it[mergeInto] = it[mergeInto].concat(b.data);
        return a;
    }, result);
}


console.log(merge(categories, items, 'items'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the categories as hash map and the key would be the id and iterate over all the items only.
then you get O(N) solution.